# What does 'clear int giX/X/X' do? Cisco

Tags: cisco

Simple question
What functionally happens when executing 'clear int giX/X/X' on a switch?  The port config looks the same afterwards, I see no difference.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

**Clear Interface** resets the hardware logic on the specific interface. It basically resets the controller.

If you were looking to clear the configs on a port, **default interface** will do the job for you.

**EDIT**
It does nothing to the configuration of the port. And yes, the GigE's controller for that specific interface is reset. It is not the same as bringing the interface up/down. Bringing the interface up/down only prevents it from taking traffic while `clear interface` is used for interfaces that are not functioning properly to rectify problems with the way the port is handling the traffic.

Comment: What controller?  This is a Gig Ethernet port?  Is this functionally the same as a shut/no shut then??  Can you verify this does nothing to any port related settings?  Need response to mark as correct.

Comment: I've edited the answer.

Comment: One caution is that on linecards where multiple ports are sharing a single ASIC, you will be clearing (or defaulting) certain things on all the ports on the same ASIC. From experience, this can cause big problems with things such as QoS.

Comment: Great clarification HAL and Ron - Thanks for updating your answer, marking as such!  I've learned a lot from you both!